# Is the team for Web Applications the same as for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, design, private-beta

I liked the design of Web Applications too much and am just asking about the team behind this great work.

Comment: Note that this is not the design of WebApps -- this is the generic design for Stack Exchange sites in beta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is the same team -- the designer is Jin Yang. More info in this will be available on the blog soon!

Comment: thanks @Jeff, @Jin Yang did a great unique design, i admire this team.